# solar potential analysis of 3d city model

Tags: 3d, software-recommendations, analysis, solar-radiation, citygml

I am looking for a free application/tool/plug-in to conduct solar potential/irradiation analysis on a 3D city model. My intention is to know how much solar energy is delivered onto the rooftops and facades of certain buildings. Once I have the information about the solar potential of buildings, I need to overlay this information with various 2D layers in GIS.

Comment: The question was closed but if you are looking for a similar tool, this one might be of some help: [Solar Radiation: Solar Energy on Building Envelopes](http://www.urban-climate.net/umep/UMEP_Manual#Solar_Radiation:_Solar_Energy_on_Building_Envelopes_.28SEBE.29)

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it myself so can't offer any advice on it, but Saga [Potential Incoming Solar Radiation](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/ta_lighting_2.html)  might be of help